# Hiding libraries, fonts ... links from index.html in react app

Tags: html, reactjs, vite

My **index.js** file (the project has been created using **vite**)

```
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see there are a lot of links i want to hide this links using some method. How can i achieve this?

Tried adding a head.html file in public folder but it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/assets/img/favi.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

        <link rel="import" href="/head.html"/>

        <title>Trip Planner</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *hide*? Do you want to remove them?

Comment: You cannot really "hide" files that the browser needs to display your page. If one has enough knowledge to look at your source code they probably also know about the network tab in the development tools. There they can see all files loaded.

Comment: @Konrad by hiding i mean not to show these links in my index.html (that can be viewed by "view page source" feature)